# Solution to handle an app on even of phone shut down

Tags: android, android-filter

I want to know if there is a provision/solution to handle shutdown/unexpected shut down of android phone when the app is being used by the user.
 One possible solution seems to be register a broadcast receiver for BATTERY_LOW. Are there any other good and effective solutions?

Comment: Please define, **completely and precisely**, what "unexpected shut down" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Broadcastreceiver...

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //handle your stuff
 }
}
```

and finally your manifest..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

for some devices this is also required

```
android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF
```

Comment: Yeah ACTION_SHUTDOWN should work. But would it be able to handle unexpected shut down? I mean if the phone suddenly shuts down due to some unknown reason, is it guaranteed that the broadcast receiver will be called?

Comment: No, but there are several reasons why a device may shutdown you cant handle. As soon as the battery has been removed, the OS crashs, and so on. You may want to use LOW_BATTERY and ACTION_SHUTDOWN, but you can't be sure. You may set a flag when shutting down and check it when the service get recreated. (ON_BOOT_COMPLETED). When the service was not shutdown successfull you may want to handle this.